# Drawing in Java 2D with fast mousemovement

Tags: java, graphics2d, repaint, java-2d, mousemotionlistener

it's going to be long, so thanks in advance for reading and/or answering :)

Edit: This [How to draw a continuous curve of repeated ovals on speedy mouse cursor dragging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36214257/how-to-draw-a-continuous-curve-of-repeated-ovals-on-speedy-mouse-cursor-dragging?rq=1) has an answer I am not completely fine with, is there no other way of doing it than drawing straight lines in between the rectangles or ovals?? (doesn't matter to me if rectangle or oval).

I have searched a lot and didn't find what I was looking for, so here we go: 
I have to create a drawing application for university and I am practically finished, my one problem is nevertheless that the mouseDragged event does not seem to be recognizing movement fast enough(?). That means, if the user draws freehand with a brush and moves the mouse too fast, the programm wont draw a "continous line of rectangles". Instead there will be many gaps in the drawing. This is how my paint() override and mousemotionlistener (for currentTool 1 which is supposed to equate a brush/pen) look like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

    g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
            AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0f));
    Iterator<Color> sc = strokeColours.iterator();
    Iterator<Color> fc = fillColours.iterator();
    Iterator<Boolean> fill = fillq.iterator();

    for (Shape s : shapes){
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        g2d.setPaint(sc.next());
        g2d.draw(s);
        g2d.setPaint(fc.next());
        if (fill.next()){
            g2d.fill(s);    
        }
    }
    if (temp!=null){
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
                AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
        g2d.setPaint(strokeColour);
        g2d.draw(temp);
        if(isfilled){
            g2d.setPaint(fillColour);
            g2d.fill(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

the motionlistener:

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            mx2=e.getX();
            my2=e.getY();
            if (currentTool==1){        
                Shape point= new Rectangle2D.Double(mx2-(0.5*penStroke),my2-(0.5*penStroke),0.5+penStroke,0.5+penStroke);
                shapes.add(point);
                addColours(strokeColour);
            }

            else if(...){...
            }


            repaint();              
        }
    } );
}
```

NB: the addColours(Color c) funtion is manually defined to add strokeColour to both strokeColours and fillColours as well as adding "true" to fillq. penStroke is defined through the use of a slider and only used for this "tool".

Comment: You could maintain information about the "points" and simply iterate the drawing of the objects between them, you'll now need to decide the iteration level

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html), some of the child classes will do Bezier curves and such. Try CubicCurve2D.Float, QuadCurve2D.Double or such, for the last detected mouse points. Note that not all "control" points of curves lie on the curve itself, but without (much) math one can get good results.